# How can I turn off the display for these orange dots on my hair particles?

Tags: particles, hair

[image]

Changing the particle select and display modes won't solve it.
The orange dots just keep floating in air when I comb the hair.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deselect "Children" from the left-hand menu under "Draw".

[image]

Comment: Thanks, what's the purpose of those orange dots tho?

Comment: If you had child particles in the hair simulation (particles tab -> children), you would see the child particles displayed there. Since you have none, they are just empty vertices that are stuck in place. Child particles are sort of a "virtual" particle thats controlled by a "real" one in a way specified in the Child Particles tab. This allows for a lot denser hair, without all the physics calculations that would go into simulating millions of particles (since only like a thousand strands control the movement of the million particles).